# Child theme cause critical error. Makes WP down

Tags: wordpress

How do I activate existing parent theme. I tried to activate and check child theme. After activation critical error occur. The problem is that I can't access dashboard and I want my parent theme back without losing anything.
Please help

Comment: You can change child theme name so that your child theme will deactivate and default theme will be activated by default & you will able to access dashboard.

Comment: My running theme will lose data or settings etc.??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to the WordPress SO

Comment: It shouldn't cause you to lose any settings if all you do is change the name of your child theme.

Comment: Changing themes does not cause data loss. You might lose widget/sidebar settings, but that's it. What is the critical error your child theme is giving you?